# Can you see the debuffs on a mob?

Tags: diablo-iii

When in a group of people killing this or that boss, due to all the effects it is difficult to see if my Witch Doctor's DoT is still on or if it ran out.  Is there a way to see the debuffs that a mob (or boss at least) has on it like the little squares the player has?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that feature is currently in the game.

This is a logical thought and would make it easier for things like that to be seen. It would be nice to make this option available in a future patch or via a mod.